# Ошибка MaterialCardView

Tags: android, android-fragment, cardview

В Material Components есть такое меню как - Card List With Drag-and-Drop, при попытке интегрировать в моё приложение возникла ошибка, помогите разобраться и исправить её.

В `styles` `style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"`

Ошибка

```
  Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 518
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at com.example.myapplication.ui.notifications.NotificationsFragment.onCreateView(NotificationsFragment.java:29)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1874)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1830)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
```

NotificationsFragment Java

```
   public class NotificationsFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final int CARD_COUNT = 30;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        MaterialCardView materialCardView = requireView().findViewById(R.id.cat_card_list_item_card);
    }

}
```

xml

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cat_card_list_item_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:minHeight="118dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cat_card_list_item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cat_card_list_item_drag_handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean"/>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, какая версия com.google.android.material:material используется?

Comment: @blind.falcon `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'`

Comment: К сожалению сложно сказать что не так, с учётом того что тема унаследована правильно. Попробуйте откатить к предыдущей версии 1.1.0, возможно это баг версии.